# Regex for valid URL characters

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to check a string before saving it to my database,

here is an example string
"Paint & Brush"

now the & is invalid, how can I use a Regex to detect this, other characters I want to check for these charaters
£, $, %, # etc

I have tried this

```
Regex RgxUrl = new Regex(@"[^A-Z0-9.\-\)\(]");
```

however the "paint & brush" example from before was still valid

Comment: No need to check. Use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`.

Comment: Try parse it using Uri.TryCreate, if it returns true it's a valid url, if not then not.

Comment: I would also like to keep valid URL characters like _ and -

Comment: How do you actually apply `RgxUrl`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not

```
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(stringURL, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
```

Read more [Uri.IsWellFormedUriString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx)

Or [Uri.TryCreate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.trycreate.aspx)

Comment: it seems to be working at the moment, will do some more testing

Answer (score 8):

Validating URLs is a common problem, so you should first consider using the available tools to do it instead of reinventing the wheel. Nevertheless, from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#List_of_allowed_URL_characters):

> Unreserved
>
> May be encoded but it is not necessary

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 - _ . ~
```

> Reserved
>
> Have to be encoded sometimes

```
! * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $ , / ? % # [ ]
```

> Further details can for example be found in RFC 3986 and http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/uri-spec.html.

Based on this, your pattern would be `[^-\]_.~!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[A-z0-9]`. You want to see if this (exclusive) patten matches any characters in your string, if so, those are probably special characters that must be encoded.

Code generated by RegexBuddy:

```
bool hasInvalidChars = false;
try {
    hasInvalidChars = Regex.IsMatch(urlToTest, @"[^-\]_.~!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[A-z0-9]", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline);
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using a regular expression for that unless you absolutely have to. Using a regular expressions means you have to test and maintain it. .NET already has a `Uri` class which you can use to verify that a string is a valid URI.

```
string urlString;
Uri uri;
if (!Uri.TryCreate(urlString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out uri)) {
    // it's not a valid URI.
}
```

You might want to examine the resulting `Uri` object further to see whether it is a HTTP one, but that should be easy.

Of course this only gives you whether the entire string was valid or not, and not which character wasn't. If you want give a more detailed error message then this method won't work.

Comment: well now it states that paint-brush (my test data) is invalid, when that is valid,

Comment: "paint-brush" is not a valid url, if you only want to check parts of the url to see whether they are valid or not then you can't use this method.

Comment: @Canvas Actually it's a valid relative url, so if you use UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute it works.